# How can I map key for X window program?

Tags: linux, xorg

For example, I want to map "j" to "page down" key for acroread program on Linux. I think maybe there is some program can do such x window keyboard event mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a script to modify the keys with `xmodmap` when you start acroread (and change them back once acroread has closed.)

For example

```
#!/bin/bash

xmodmap -e "keycode 44 = Next"
xmodmap -e "keycode 45 = Prior"
/usr/bin/acroread 
xmodmap -e "keycode 44 = j J"
xmodmap -e "keycode 45 = k K"
```

Instead of running acroread directly, you run this script.